# JavaScript culture sensitive currency formatting

Tags: javascript, localization, currency

How can i format currency related data in a manner that is culture aware in JavaScript?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

There is the `Number.localeFormat()` function, but I'm not sure it's what you're after.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb310813.aspx

Comment: this is an ASP.NET extension function, not native JS

Answer (score 3):

So I know this is an old question, but incase anyone else shows up looking for similar answers, in modern JavaScript you can use

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number)
```

For more info here is the reference doc.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Answer (score 2):

Dojo has a [currency formatter](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/dojo/HEAD/dojo.currency.format) that's locale aware.

If you don't want to include Dojo in your project just for this function, then perhaps you can localize the currency in your back-end?

Comment: I believe the Dojo currecy formatting is based on XML data from the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (http://unicode.org/cldr). While Dojo will do the hard work for you, if you don't want to use it you can get the raw data from there.

Answer (score 1):

Number.toLocaleString (implemented in   JavaScript 1.5, ECMAScript 3rd Edition)

```
var number = 3500;
console.log(number.toLocaleString()); /* Displays "3,500" in English locale */
```

[Docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

Comment: This might not work in a node.js environment. you might need to load 'intl' and locale files.